# Api-Platform + Swagger: group operations/entities by Doctrine or ApiPlatform mapping

Tags: doctrine-orm, entitymanager, api-platform.com, doctrine-mapping

I have `config/packages/api_platform.yaml`:

```yaml
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: 
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/old/Entity'
```

In both namespaces I have entities with the same name. What do I have to do for them to display in `/docs` grouped into different mappings and not by entity class name alone.

How do I configure prefix "globally" for each of the namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Platform does not provide this configuration right now you will have to decorate the `OpenApiFactory` like [this](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#overriding-the-openapi-specification)

The swagger documentation groups them by their `tags`

```php
<?php
// src/OpenApi/OpenApiFactory.php

namespace App\OpenApi;

use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Factory\OpenApiFactoryInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\OpenApi;
use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Model;

final class OpenApiFactory implements OpenApiFactoryInterface
{
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(OpenApiFactoryInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function __invoke(array $context = []): OpenApi
    {
        $openApi = $this->decorated->__invoke($context);

        $paths = $openApi->getPaths()->getPaths();

        $filteredPaths = new Model\Paths();
        foreach ($paths as $path => $pathItem) {
            // Here you can check the tags for each Operations
            // Add custom logic with the snippet below
        }

        return $openApi->withPaths($filteredPaths);
    }
}
```

Here come the dirty part, tags will be `EntityName` and not full namespace name
I would make a list of all old entity, filter the current tag on it and change to old or new
(Below is pseudo-code)

```php
$OldEntityList = ['entity1', 'entity2', ...]
foreach ($Operations as $op) {
  if (in_array($op->getTags(), $OldEntityList) {
     $op->withTags('old');
  } else {
     $op->withTags('new');
  }
}
```

Comment: This is ugly AF.

Comment: Since the swagger is generated idk how to do better, you can add `openapi_context` to ALL entity or try using PHP Reflector class to know if it's old/new directory

Comment: I'm not complaining at you. Just at the lack of a global setting for that in the config. For example with paths nested with labels, like `path => label`, or `label => [ paths, ... ]`.